# Problem with using Mat-Dialog in another injectable service in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-dialog

this is the module

```
    @NgModule({
        imports: [],
        declarations: [VariableDialogComponent],
        providers: [OutputFieldsService]
    })
    export class AModule {}
```

this is the OutputFieldsService

```
@Injectable()
export class OutputFieldsService {
    constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}
    public addParameter() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(VariableDialogComponent, {
        data: dt,
        disableClose: true,
        minWidth: '30%'
    });
    return dialogRef.afterClosed()
  }
}
```

and AModule is lazyloaded so every time I try to access that module will get this error

[image]

**And from what I understand the error is very misleading**

the error will disappear when I remove the open VariableDialogComponent dialog from the service

and the service and component are in the same module so I don't understand why I get this error

am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the reason why this is happening.
but fix it with this method:
im passing the component as an argument, this way I don't mention the VariableDialogComponent inside the service

Module

```
    @NgModule({
        imports: [],
        declarations: [VariableDialogComponent],
        providers: [OutputFieldsService]
    })
    export class AModule {}
```

OutputFieldsService

```
@Injectable()
export class OutputFieldsService {
    constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}
    public addParameter(component: ComponentType<any>) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(component, {
        data: dt,
        disableClose: true,
        minWidth: '30%'
    });
    return dialogRef.afterClosed()
  }
}
```

And then

```
this.outputFieldsService.addParameter(VariableDialogComponent)
```